# Writing to csv-file with npm csv-writer not working, but no error message appearing

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, npm, electron

I am trying to write to a CSV-file from my electron renderer.js process. Unfortunately, most of the time the writing isn't working, and the `.then` addition isn't executed. Strangely, there is no kind of error message or anything that would tell me my mistake. Some few times it has worked though, the file was written but the confirmation from `.then` wasn't displayed in the console. I don't have any clue as to what went differently these times.

When reloading the application with `ctrl+r` after the failed attempt the saving process is run again (somehow the `onclick` attribute of a button, containing a function call for the function all this stuff here ↓ is in) and that always works (including the .`then` call).

My code:

```
var settings = [
    ["devtools", false, devtools, ""],
    ["language", "en", language, ""]
]
var csvWriter = window.createCsvWriter({
    header: ['ABBREVIATION', 'DEFAULT', 'CUSTOM', ''],
    path: 'saves/settings.csv'
});

csvWriter.writeRecords(settings)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Saved succesfully!');
    });
```

`window.createCsvWriter` is a preloaded script, `devtools` and `language` are script wide variables that are updated shortly before this.

I have no idea where the error is coming from, as it can't be in the path or something like that as it has run successfully multiple times. I even tried to follow the debugging process line by line, but all I think I have found out is that the settings array is fully dealt with, the script ends somewhere in a jungle of loops and if-clauses concerning the path or something. 
I also know that a normal CSV-file wouldn't have a comma on the end of the rows, my code importing the settings later just can't deal with that, which I will fix later. If you need any more information just ask.

EDIT:
I just followed the code again line by line and notices that it stops after the `return __awaiter()` in `CsvWriter.prptotype.writeRecords = function (records) {...}`. `records` is an array with the correct data for the CSV. Maybe that is useful information.

EDIT2:
I tried using `fs.writeFile()` to write and it has the same problem, the file became empty and there was no error. I noticed though, that when reloading (remember originally it worked when reloading) it sent errors or confirmations for all the attempts of that session at once, and the file was written (if there were confirmations). So I assume the problem is something that stops the code from fully running until the page is reloaded. Any ideas what that could be? I imagine it's possible that it's another script or something global.

I don't have any breakpoints stopping the code.

Comment: Don't know – but which `console` are you looking at? The `render` processes have their own console connected to the window.

Comment: Neither the VSCode console nor the one inside the electron window have any messages inside. Most other errors appeared in the electron one, so I expected it to be there

Answer (score 1):

`writeRecords` returns a promise that is either resolved or rejected. You code only handles the 'resolved' path and you ignore any rejection. Try this, it could reveal the error:

```
csvWriter.writeRecords(settings)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Saved succesfully!');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Save failed', err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the catch part. Sadly, it still doesn't always work and there is also no error message.